# How do I change just one column (field) in MySQL with random tuple value in python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I tried to do this but it would still prompt an error: "Error while connecting to MySQL Could not process parameters: int(2564), it must be of type list, tuple **and** Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement"

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import random

try:
    fypdb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', port='3306',
                                         database='userdbfyp',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='root')
    if fypdb.is_connected():
        db_Info = fypdb.get_server_info()
        print("Connected to MySQL Server version", db_Info)
        tuple = (2564, 5343, 4035, 4496)
        randomTup = random.choice(tuple)
        cursor = fypdb.cursor()
        cursor.execute("UPDATE employee2 SET unCode = (randomTup) WHERE gender = 'm'")
        fypdb.commit()
```

Comment: that makes no sense a column like `unCode` will be changed, but you will put it into all rows teh new value, so which emplolyer should be chnaged

Answer (score 0):

- You are passing the value of the `randomTup` wrongly as far as I understand.
- Updated code

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import random

try:
    fypdb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        port='3306',
        database='userdbfyp',
        user='root',
        password='root'
    )
    if fypdb.is_connected():
        db_Info = fypdb.get_server_info()
        print("Connected to MySQL Server version", db_Info)
        values = (2564, 5343, 4035, 4496)
        randomTup = random.choice(values)
        cursor = fypdb.cursor()
        cursor.execute("UPDATE employee2 SET unCode = %s WHERE gender = 'm'", (randomTup,))
        fypdb.commit()
except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
finally:
    if fypdb.is_connected():
        cursor.close()
        fypdb.close()
```

- The %s in the SQL statement is a placeholder that will be replaced with the value from the tuple (randomTup,). The comma in (randomTup,) is necessary to indicate that it's a tuple with a single value. You can refer the documentation [here](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html).
- Also, you can add exception handling to catch any errors that may occur during the connection or execution of the SQL statement. Finally, the cursor and fypdb objects are closed in the finally block to ensure proper cleanup. So that you don't have unwanted connection opened up, you will just keep a lot of connection open which can cause a issue in future.